# How to resolve "uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a `html/javascript/php` code as shown below in which at the `3rd echo statement`, I have added a button which on click calls on `deleteAttribute()` function.

 
On the 3rd echo statement `(type = "button")`, I am getting an error:

```
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"
```

**html/javascript/php:**

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<?php 
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '        <dt><a href="abcde.php?id='.rawurlencode($row['attribute']).'&action=' . rawurlencode($row['action']).'&name=' . rawurlencode($row['map_value_name']).'">'."\n";
        echo '                '.$row['attribute'].'</a> ('.$row['owner'].')'."\n";
        echo '        <input type="button" value ="Delete" class="btn btn-map btn-danger" onclick="deleteAttribute('.$row['attribute'].')"/>';
        echo '        </dt>'."\n";
        echo '        <dd>'."\n";
        echo '            '.$row['description']."\n";
        echo '        </dd>'."\n";
    }
?>
</body>
    <script>
        function deleteAttribute(attribute) {
            if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' +attribute+ ' ?')){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    attribute: attribute
                },
            });
        }}
    </script>
</html>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in 3rd echo statement in the while loop so that I can avoid this error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"`.

[image]

Comment: Looks fine to me, try checking the values in your $row, $row['attribute']

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue when passing the `$row['attribute']` the quote was mixing so an easy solution is to wrap it in a variable and pass that to the function as below:

```
<body>
<?php
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '        <dt><a href="submit-address.php?id='.rawurlencode($row['attribute']).'&action=' . rawurlencode($row['action']).'&name=' . rawurlencode($row['map_value_name']).'">'."\n";
  echo '                '.$row['attribute'].'</a> ('.$row['owner'].')'."\n";
  $attribute = $row['attribute'];
  echo '        <input type="button" value ="Delete" class="btn btn-map btn-danger" onclick="deleteAttribute('.$attribute.')"/>';
  echo '        </dt>'."\n";
echo '        <dd>'."\n";
  echo '            '.$row['description']."\n";
  echo '        </dd>'."\n";
}
?>
</body>
```

Here is the working screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I've added the screenshot that it is working.

Comment: can you copy and paste the whole body part and replace it with your code and maybe hard reload your browser? Maybe cache issue

Comment: can you provide the updated version of code and full screenshot?

Comment: Yes, I've added the working screenshot in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The SyntaxError that you are encountering is a result of failing to encapsulate your filename.

Simply changing `onclick="deleteAttribute(test png000)"` to `onclick="deleteAttribute('test png000')"` should resolve your syntaxual error.

Without proper encapulation, your script thinks "test png000" is two seperate variables instead of a string that you are attemtping to pass into your funciton.

On closing I did want to bring your attention to utilizing [alternative syntax for control structures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) that will make your codebase more readable and easily debugged without making a mess with redundant echos.

Additionally, instead of concatinating a long list of URL encoded values into a query, you could simply take advantage of PHP's [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to make your code more readable while keeping things tidy. Please take my code below in reference.

I hope this helps!

```
<body>
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <dt>
            <a href="abcde.php?id=<?php echo http_build_query(array('id' => $row['attribute'], 'action' => $row['action'], 'name' => $row['map_value_name'])); ?>">
                <?php echo $row['attribute']; ?>
            </a>
            
            (<?php echo $row['owner']; ?>)
            
            <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-map btn-danger" onclick="deleteAttribute('<?php echo $row['attribute']; ?>')"/>
        </dt>
        
        <dd>
            <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
        </dd>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</body>

<script>
    function deleteAttribute(attribute) {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + attribute + ' ?')) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {
                    attribute: attribute
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any way I can fix this in echo ?

Comment: @flash its in the solution, mate. You encapsulate the filename where you're trying to pass it off as a string to the function.